# I am a having a middle dot at the end of my ink in navbar. I have not used &middot nor &bull

Tags: html, css, web, drop-down-menu, navbar

[Having the problem here in solutions link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ksRR.png)

here is the HTML code, normally if I use a button there is no such dot, however, if I use ul or li this occurs. Maybe it is because I am adding a simple HTML/CSS dropdown element in a bootstrap navigation bar?

```
<div class="dropdown">
                            <ul onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Solutions   </ul>
                            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                              <a href="compsupport.html">Computer Support</a>
                              <a href="Printer_Solutions.html">Printer Solutions</a>
                              <a href="Email & Social Media Solutions.html">Email/Social Media Support</a>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
```

I have added the CSS code below, also the link contains the image depicting my problem.

```
 .dropdown{
     padding-top: 0.7em;
}
 .dropbtn ul {
     list-style: none;
}
 .dropbtn li{
     background-color: transparent;
     color:grey;
     font-size: 18px;
     font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT','Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
     border: none;
     position:fixed;
     line-height:50px;
     padding-top: 5em;
     padding-bottom: 20em;
}
.dropbtn:hover,.dropbtn:focus,.dropbtn:after {
     background-color:transparent;
     color:blue;
}
.dropdown {
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
}

 .dropdown-content {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #f1f1f1;
     min-width: 160px;
     z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
     color:grey;
     padding: 12px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd
}
 .dropdown-content a:hover {
    color:black
}
.show {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Add your code snippet, because I tried the code you have appended in the question and I cannot find any dot at the end of `solutions`

Comment: Please could you put up a snippet which we can run as I cannot replicate the problem on the code you have given. However, watch usage of ampersand in filenames.

Comment: I can't* replicate the issue using the markup you've provided; I'd suggest using your browser's element inspector (F12, or Ctrl+Shift+C) to look at the element in question and tracing the problem. The only weird thing I see in your markup is the extra three spaces after the word "Solutions." Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's damn simple man Just copy my code

```css
dropbtn ul {

  list-style: none;

}
```

Comment: it does not have any effect, I think the problem is different.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to guess what that issue is, without seeing your code. (Given is not enough).
By the way you can check it out with this code snippet. I have slightly changed your HTML.

```css
  .dropdown{
    padding-top: 0.7em;
  }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <ul onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">
    <li>
      <span>Solutions</span>   
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="compsupport.html">Computer Support</a>
        <a href="Printer_Solutions.html">Printer Solutions</a>
        <a href="Email & Social Media Solutions.html">Email/Social Media Support</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i have added the CSS part

Comment: also, i tried your code but the dot is not removed

Comment: Just checked it with your css, but I can't see any dot at the end of 'solution'

Comment: Must be something else